# UiTextField changes font while editing in Swift 1.2 & 2.0

Tags: ios, uikit

I have a UITextField with a custom font, everything worked fine until Swift update to 1.2 and 2.0. Afterwards, each time I try to edit a text field, it changes its font to a different one that seems a sort of Times New Roman. Does anyone have experience of that?

Comment: How is this Swift's fault? If anything, it's a UIKit framework bug. Did you report to Apple?

Answer (score 10):

I came across this same issue and figured out a solution. The problem boils down to `setSecureTextEntry` changing the font when it is set, and not changing it back when it is unset. In fact, you can never change the font back as long as your `UITextField` has first responder.

The trick is to `resignFirstResponder` before you call `setSecureTextEntry:` and then `becomeFirstResponder` again. This ***will*** work (as of iOS 9.2), but it triggers the keyboard show/hide animation and will cause the screen to "shake". To get around that, you'll need to kill the keyboard animation as well.

Here's my full solution:

```
- (void)setSecureTextEntry:(BOOL)secureTextEntry {

    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    [UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{

        BOOL resumeResponder = NO;
        if([[weakSelf textEntryField] isFirstResponder]) {
            resumeResponder = YES;
            [[weakSelf textEntryField] resignFirstResponder];
        }

        [[weakSelf textEntryField] setSecureTextEntry:secureTextEntry];

        if(resumeResponder) {
            [[weakSelf textEntryField] becomeFirstResponder];
        }
    }];
}
```

PS: This isn't a Swift bug. It's a UIKit bug. I had the same issue with Objective-C.

Comment: Do not waist time for other solution. This one is best!

Comment: This solution is definitely the best!!

Answer (score 7):

I had a weird case of fonts changing its size and font type, when secureTextEntry for an UiTextField was toggled by using a button action.
[image]
Had to explicitly manage font for the UiTextField by using these lines of code:

```
password.font = UIFont(name: "systemFont", size: 14)
password.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14)
```

Complete Code used in the **Show Password Button**:

```
//Function associated with the button for show password option
@IBAction func switchShowPasswordAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        if showPassword{
            showPassword  = false
            password.secureTextEntry = !showPassword

        }else{
            showPassword = true
            password.secureTextEntry = !showPassword
        }

        //Changing font fix
        password.font = UIFont(name: "systemFont", size: 14)
        password.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14)
}
```

Post applying this change:
[image]

Comment: actually I just need 1 line `password.font = UIFont(name: "systemFont", size: 14)` . I guess that because there is no font named *systemFont*, the system will fall back to the default system font. Seems quite hacky though.

Comment: Pacemoon, Yeah it's hacky but had no other option/help around.
I did try to have it done in one line but failed to have the exact effect on the size, so added in that extra line.

Comment: What if we have to use custom font.

Comment: could just set the font to nil

Comment: What you suggest is great, but it works only if we use the default setting. A better solution IMO would be to take the current font, assign the font of the text field to nil, and then reassign it back to the font from step 1. `if let currentFont = passwordTextField.font { passwordTextField.font = nil; passwordTextField.font = currentFont; }`

Answer (score 1):

Since I used custom fonts we need to preserve the original font. Create an extension to `UITextField`:

```
extension UITextField {
    func enablePasswordModeWithShowHide() {
        secureTextEntry = false
        let showButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System)
        showButton.setTitle("HIDE", forState: .Normal)
        showButton.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .Right
        showButton.sizeToFit()
        rightView = showButton
        rightViewMode = .Always
        showButton.addTarget(self, action: "handleShowHideTapped", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        showButton.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }

    func handleShowHideTapped() {
        secureTextEntry = !secureTextEntry
        let font = self.font
        self.font = nil
        self.font = font
        if let oldText = text {
            text = "";
            text = oldText;
        }

        if let button = rightView as? UIButton {
            button.setTitle(secureTextEntry ? "SHOW" : "HIDE", forState: .Normal)
            button.sizeToFit()
        }
    }
}
```

Where it could be implemented like this:

```
passwordTextField.enablePasswordModeWithShowHide()
```

Answer (score 1):

All of these answers pretty much work, but I had to use a different solution to achieve the results I needed, considering I'm using a custom font.

You need to make the text field `attributed` in the storyboard inspector pane for the UITextField, as follows:

[image: attributed selected in inspector]

Then, in code, you need to manage the toggling of the visibility, setting the attributed text each time, to ensure its properly formatted.  I also resignFirstResponder() on the field just to take care of some positioning glitch that I still haven't figured out yet.

```
func toggleShowPass() {
    self.showing = !showing

    txtpassword.secureTextEntry = !showing
    textFieldPassword.resignFirstResponder()

    let string = textFieldPassword.text!
    let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string)

    textFieldPassword.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 16.0)!, range: NSMakeRange(0, string.characters.count))
    textFieldPassword.attributedText = attrString

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It solves my problem when changing the text attribute of my UITextView in the storyboard to "Attributed".

Answer (score 0):

Set defaultTextAttributes with custom font attribute after toggling the secureTextEntry flag

NSDictionary *attrsDictionary =
                @{ NSFontAttributeName://customfont};
_passwordtextfield.defaultTextAttributes = attrsDictionary;

Answer (score 0):

I had to apply the following solution with latest Xcode 7.1.1 which actually worked in my case I suspect this issue is of framework.

```
- (IBAction)btnPasswordShowAction:(id)sender {


        self.txtPassword.secureTextEntry = !self.txtPassword.secureTextEntry;

        NSString *tmpString = self.txtPassword.text;
        self.txtPassword.text = @" ";
        self.txtPassword.text = tmpString;

       [self.txtPassword setFont:nil];
       self.txtPassword.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Regular" size:16.0];
  }

 #pragma mark -  Textfield Delegate Methods

 - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
   {
       [self.txtPassword setFont:nil];
       self.txtPassword.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Regular" size:16.0];
   }


   - (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
    {
        [self.txtPassword setFont:nil];
        self.txtPassword.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Regular" size:16.0];
         return YES;
   }
```