# Show "#" instead of "bullets" in UITextField for "Secure Text Entry"

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have a requirement to show **"#"** instead of **bullets** for password field.
But as there is no default option available for it in UITextField.

I have tried to write custom logic in **"shouldChangeCharactersInRange"**
But i am not able to handle the index when user will remove or add any specific character from in-between.

So here are my questions :-
 1. Do i need to find any library
 2. There is any other default option available for it?
 3. Need to write custom logic for it? If so where i can handle it correctly **"shouldChangeCharactersInRange"** or **"textFieldDidChange"**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [change the secure password character in UITextfield](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280069/change-the-secure-password-character-in-uitextfield)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. No you dont need to find any 3rd party library for this logic
2. No there is no default option available for your need
3. Yes, you need to write a custom logic for your demand, So here it goes...

   ```
   var passwordText = String()

   func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

   if textField == textFieldPassword {

       var hashPassword = String()
       let newChar = string.characters.first
       let offsetToUpdate = passwordText.index(passwordText.startIndex, offsetBy: range.location)

       if string == "" {
           passwordText.remove(at: offsetToUpdate)
           return true
       }
       else { passwordText.insert(newChar!, at: offsetToUpdate) }

       for _ in passwordText.characters {  hashPassword += "#" }
       textField.text = hashPassword
       return false
   }
   ```

## Swift 4:-

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    if textField == textFieldPassword {

        var hashPassword = String()
        let newChar = string.first
        let offsetToUpdate = passwordText.index(passwordText.startIndex, offsetBy: range.location)

        if string == "" {
            passwordText.remove(at: offsetToUpdate)
            return true
        }
        else { passwordText.insert(newChar!, at: offsetToUpdate) }

        for _ in 0..<passwordText.count {  hashPassword += "#" }
        textField.text = hashPassword
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But i am using swift 2.3 so what would be alternative for this function -- let offsetToUpdate = passwordText.index -- It says String has no member index.

Comment: Bro that was swift 3 syntax, let me search the replacement for you !!

Comment: Hey, checkout this link to insert new char in string : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31550835/convert-a-string-to-an-array-of-characters-swift-2-0

Comment: Check [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30403550/how-can-i-change-the-dots-to-another-character-on-password-field-in-ios-swift) and [UITextField secureTextEntry bullets with a custom font?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20969451/uitextfield-securetextentry-bullets-with-a-custom-font)

Comment: But this line is not inserting a new character? This is just checking index?

Comment: Yes you need to find the index to append  or remove the character. Find the replacement of this line and you are good to go, actually i dont have xCode 7.x.

Comment: Got anything ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144028/discussion-between-awesome-apple-and-mr-bean).

Comment: @Mr.BeanI am getting this error Thread 1: Fatal error: String index is out of bounds, Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Use a normal textfield without the secure input option. When a user enters a character, save it to a string variable, and replace it in the textfield with the character you wish to present instead of the bullets.

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {

   let textField = UITextField(frame :CGRect(x:16,y:50,width:200,height: 40))
    override func viewDidLoad() {
               super.viewDidLoad()

             textField.delegate = self
             self.view.addSubview(textField)
               textField.becomeFirstResponder()
}

var password: String = ""
  func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool{

       password = password+string
       textField.text = textField.text!+"#"//Character you want
       print("\(password)")
       return false
  }
}
```

This is in Swift 2. Hope it Helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Improved Mr. Bean's answer in swift 5. To fix Copy&Paste bugs.

```
var passNSString : NSString = ""
    
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        
        var hashPassword = String()
        
        passNSString = passNSString.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string) as NSString
        for _ in 0..<passNSString.length {  hashPassword += "#" }
        textField.text = hashPassword
        print("str", passNSString)
        return false
        
    }
```