# How to turn off character previews letter pop ups?

Tags: ios, swift

I want a fully secure text entry in one of my text fields.
I set `isSecureTextEntry` to `true`
But when a user presses a key, the pressed character will pop up for the preview and I need to disable this.

Is there any way I can do that?

I know it can be turned off by the user in settings but I need to do that in code myself.

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? If you eman that iOS shows the actual character for a small period of time, this is the default iOS behavior.

Comment: Are you looking for this code? :
var isSecure = true
if(isSecure == true) {
            passwordTF.secureTextEntry = false
        } else {
            passwordTF.secureTextEntry = true
        }

        isSecure = !isSecure

Comment: are you mean the auto suggestion in keyboard

Comment: @inexcitus I added a screenshot I want to know is there any way to change this behavior?

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik No

Comment: I am afraid you need to use your own customized UITextField described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48185533/how-to-hide-passwords-in-a-uitextfield-like?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @SasanSoroush - by default behaviour of keyboard, we cant handle this, if you need then go with keyboard extension.