# Swift 4.2: UITextField secureEntryText using Image instead of Default Bullets

Tags: ios, swift

I want to make a custom class of UITextField where secureTextEntry turned on, so when I'm typing text, the text will hidden and changed to UIImage instead of default "bullets".

This question is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20969451/uitextfield-securetextentry-bullets-with-a-custom-font), but instead of custom fonts, I want to use UIImage instead. Anyone know how?

Here's the example of expected result:
[image]

and here's my current customclass:

```
import UIKit
@IBDesignable
class SecuredBorderTextField: UITextField {
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After two days struggling with this, I come to solution that can trick this. I'm creating `stackView` that contain of `UITextField`. I create array for temporary text that filled the `UITextField`. Then, when the UITextField is filled by some character, I programmatically add `UIImage`. In my code, will look like this.

```
let chars = Array(shieldString)
for (index, char) in chars.enumerated() {
                if let tmp = self.stackView.arrangedSubviews[index] as? UITextField {
                    let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "dotImage")!)
                    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 28, height: 28)
                    imageView.center = CGPoint(x: tmp.frame.size.width  / 2, y: tmp.frame.size.height / 2)
                    imageView.tag = 100
                    tmp.addSubview(imageView)
                }
 }
```

And for clear the Image, just using this. I use tag so I can delete specific subview.

```
for ele in self.stackView.arrangedSubviews {
                if let viewWithTag = self.view.viewWithTag(100) {
                    viewWithTag.removeFromSuperview()
                }
}
```

I know that this not custom class, and quiet messy, but if you in a rush like me, this probably will save you.