# Secure iOS textfield seems to resize text size. How to avoid this?

Tags: ios, textfield

I am having a strange issue with a secure textfield in iOS7. It may seem a stupid detail, but I want to fix it.

It turns out I have two textfields, one to insert the username and the second one as an input for the user password. The thing is, when I insert text into the password field, the dots size becomes smaller, but when this secure textfield stops being the first responder, the size of the dots becomes the one it should be (bigger than when being the first responder).

As an ilustration, take a look at these two images extracted from my app:

Non first responder:

[image: Non first responder]

First responder:

[image]

As you can see, the size of the dots changes depending on whether the secure textfield is the first responder or not.

Is there any way to avoid this resizing?

Thank you all in advance.

Additional info:

- I am using an external text font which seems to work fine on the textfields.
- The text size of both textfields is 17.0.
- Both font type and font size are set in the ViewDidLoad method of the ViewController where the textfields are.

Comment: It seems like it's a font issue: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19475918/1153630

Comment: Thank you very much @Jugale ! That solved my problem. I don't know how I didn't find that question before.

Comment: i have just tried the solution it help me to solve the problem
[No more resize my font of the secure entry textField](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42850801/3903182)